# is there any impact when calling onclick function without a javascript method?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, javascript, lightning-events

I have a component where there is a button with onclick function

```
<a class="notifLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" id="buttonDropdownOne" aria-expanded="false" onclick="{!c.readNotifs}">
```

in controller the readNotifs function is not implemented since its not necessary to execute any function

```
({

doInit : function(component, event, helper) {

                helper.refreshComponentOne(component, helper); 
            }
      })
```

will this make any impact since the button click function is not implemented?

Comment: You'll probably just get an error in the console or runtime error when the component loads.  Is there any reason why you can't just leave out the onclick handler?  Or just add an empty function to your controller?

Answer (score 0):

The user would a get dismissable popup error (either "Sorry for Interrupting", or "We experienced an error"), or just an error on the console (e.g. in Lightning Out).

In any case, you should not do this in production code. However, if you want to make sure you don't "forget" a method while you're developing the code, intentionally leaving it out would give you a very strong reminder that a given function hasn't been implemented yet.

This popup is a modal and must be dismissed, so this technique should not be used in production code, as it is disruptive to the user experience.